# replicate rdlc design view programmatically without data

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reporting

I wish to generate a simple preview of a rdlc report in c# code pretty much exactly as it looks in Visual Studio Design mode. I don't want to connect to the database or populate any data into the preview.

I'm not familiar with the Reporting library but I've examined the xml rdlc file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the RDLC files manually.  I have done this extensively in the past.  You need to generate XSD files and then build the report RDLC with some code.  It is not a simple task.

Take a look here:  http://gotreportviewer.com/

On the right side there are a couple of links that explain how to dynamically create reports.  Buckle up, you are in for a long ride.

Comment: I have rldc files already that I may not alter. But thanks for the link